# how to store a certain range of string into list

Tags: python

I want have python file that i want to read and capture its def and code inside def itself and store into (containDEF1)list. How to capture def hello and all of its code inside and store into an (containDEF1)list and then the next def hello2 and inside the code and store as new element into (containDEF1). And continue until the last def(). And ignore those are not in the block level of def. I have list what i did below if got any new ideas on how to achieve this please tell thanks.

python file:

```
#!C:\Python\Python39\python.exe
print ('Content-type: text/html\n\n')

    def hello(self):
        try:
            global testcaseResult
    
            assert self.Remedy.returnStatus
            assert self.Remedy.returnStatus
            print(self.Remedy.returnMessage)
    
        =self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_hide(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=5)
        =self.Remedy.ResolutionCatPopulation(self, driver, ResoCat1, ResoCat2, ResoCat3=None)
    
    def hello2(self):
        try:
         global testcaseResult

         assert self.Remedy.returnStatus
         assert self.Remedy.returnStatus
         print(self.Remedy.returnMessage)
            =self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)
    
    def hello3(self):
        =self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)

print(funcs)
print(funcs)
```

What i did:

```
with open("test70.py", 'r') as inFile:
     funcs = inFile.read().split('\n\n')
     print(funcs)
     
    
     for elem in funcs:
      if elem.startswith('def'):
          containDEF1.append(elem)


print(containDEF1)
```

**output of print(func)**

```
["#!C:\\Users\\cxt764\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python.exe\nprint ('Content-type: text/html\\n\\n')", 'def hello(self):\n\ttry:\n\t\tglobal testcaseResult', '\t\tassert self.Remedy.returnStatus\n\t\tassert self.Remedy.returnStatus\n\t\tprint(self.Remedy.returnMessage)', '\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_hide(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=5)\n\t=self.Remedy.ResolutionCatPopulation(self, driver, ResoCat1, ResoCat2, ResoCat3=None)', 'def hello2(self):\n\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)', 'def hello3(self):\n\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)', 'def hello4(self):\n\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)']
```

**output of print(containDEF1):**

```
['def hello(self):\n\ttry:\n\t\tglobal testcaseResult', 'def hello2(self):\n\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)', 'def hello3(self):\n\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)', 'def hello4(self):\n\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_get_text(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=30)']
```

problem: in the `def hello(self)` missing some part of the code `'\t\tassert self.Remedy.returnStatus\n\t\tassert self.Remedy.returnStatus\n\t\tprint(self.Remedy.returnMessage)', '\t=self.MOSS IOS.element_wait_by_xpath_hide(self, mossDriver, action_msg, by_xpath, timeout=5)\n\t=self.Remedy.ResolutionCatPopulation(self, driver, ResoCat1, ResoCat2, ResoCat3=None)',` should be also in def hello as one element.

Comment: `split('\n\n')` this assumes that each function `def` is preceded by exactly one blank line, and no other blank lines within the `def`. In Python, blocks are defined by indentation, not blank lines, so maybe you should try something in that direction.

Comment: @tobias_k do you mean that instead of using \n\n to track the def block, try using \s\s? am i right?

Comment: I suggest you read it one line at a time then tokenise based on whitespace. If the first token == 'def' then you'll need to make a note of the whitespace that precedes it. On subsequent lines you're only interested in those with a greater level of indentation. Once the indentation level is <= to that which you noted previously, you've reached the end of the function. You need to ignore any/all blank lines. If there are sections of the code that have been "blocked out" (e.g. with triple quotes) you'll have to keep track of that too. The code that you've presented is syntactically incorrect

Comment: Instead of trying to parse it yourself, I suggest you use the `ast` module to parse it for you.